# Multiple selection and graph export in Excel Online

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I'm exploring Microsoft's online Office Suite and I have some questions about Excel Online.

1) Is it possible to multi-select multiple cells? I'm referring to the action in the "classic" version where selection can be done using **<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + left click** on multiple, disconnected cells.

2) Is it possible (and if so, how) to export a graph directly in PNG/GIF/(any_other_image_format)?

3) If these features are not present in the free Office version, maybe the paid Office 365 version has them?

Comment: For questions 1 & 2 have you tried it out and couldn't do it?

Comment: Yes, I tried using different browser, with no luck.

Comment: The answer for question-1 is **NO**. I tried it and its not possible (at least from Google Chrome). For question-2, there are no options to export a graph (chart) from the online suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Bad News. I can confirm positively that Excel Online does not currently support non-sequential multi-select for cells. (traditionally done by holding `cmd` on MacOS, or `ctrl` everywhere else and selecting non-adjacent cells with the mouse). Supporting evidence:

- [The official MS help document](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-in-Excel-Online-9271deca-569e-4ad2-8475-9ff98b8bcce3) conspicuously does not list that action under "Excel Online commands: Select cells, rows and columns, and objects" (Near bottom of page)
- [The user community has been asking for this feature](https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/274580-excel-online/suggestions/10676208-there-is-no-way-to-select-non-adjacent-cells-as-in) for more than two years as of October 2017
- I have not personally found the feature to be anywhere in the UI

2) It's a hack, but probably the easiest way to export a graph is to just maximize the graph size in the window, and then take a screenshot of it. (`cmd-shift-4` on MacOS will let you crop the screenshot when it's taken. File will be PNG and saved to the desktop. On Windows I have no idea but chances are it can be done.)

3) I'm testing with Enterprise version of Office 365, so it's not likely there is any difference.